# kineticjs how to play video

Tags: html5-video, kineticjs

I need to add video to the stage and then play on mouse click using kineticjs.

I searched a lot for this but have not found any working code

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an HTML5 `<video>` tag to your DOM with the appropriate `<source>` tags. Assign the video element to a variable. Create a `Kinetic.Image` for your video to play on. Then play the video by clicking on some object (maybe the image, maybe a "play" button you placed on the stage) and use the following function to draw the video to the image. For best results, hide the video by placing it absolutely offscreen. The image can be any size, but to prevent distortion, the image should be the same aspect ratio as the video.

```
$('body').append('<div id="video' + vid + '" class="offscreen"></div>');
var vidobj = '<video width="' + vw + '" height="' + vh + ' preload="auto"><source src="' + vsrc + '" type="video/mp4"></source></video>';
$('#video' + vid).html(vidobj);
var video = $('#video' + vid + ' > video').get(0);
var img = new Kinetic.Image({name : 'video', x : vx, y : vy, width : vw, height : vh, image : video});
layer.add(img);
video.play();
setVideo(video,img);

function setVideo(v,i) {
    if (!v.paused && !v.ended) {
        i.setImage(v);
        cvsObj.modal.draw();
        setTimeout(setVideo,20,v,i);
    }
}
```

v = your video, i = the image object.

EDITED to show creation of HTML5 video tag and Kinetic.Image(). Variables : vid = video id (unique), vw = video width, vh = video height, vx = video x coordinate (for canvas), vy = video y coordinate, vsrc = video source (path to file).

Comment: can you show me the example for creating Kinetic.Image for video. Thanks

Comment: Added everything you should need to create video directly on the Kinetic.JS canvas. Image can be placed anywhere, even inside a group, and can be sized any way you want (for instance, in the above, vw and vh for image can be changed to vw *2, vh * 2 to double the size of the video.

Comment: Here's the page I used as a reference. I merely converted the basic canvas code into KineticJS code. http://html5doctor.com/video-canvas-magic/

Answer (score 1):

why does video have to be inside the stage?  Couldn't you just place an HTML5 video element on  top of the stage?

Comment: I need to show video after some elements appeared on the stage on the particular location, I am adding elements dynamically where as I am not able to add video to stage as image object of kineticjs

Comment: @Eric It's OK, bro, I got this one. ;)